# How can I create DateTime HTML output?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

When I set the type of form element to Zend\Form\Element\Date the view helper nicely creates HTML for a drop down calendar.  However, when I change it to **Zend\Form\Element\DateTime**, not only am I not getting a time input but the date input has reverted to a text input.

What is the easiest way to get a DateTime HTML form element drawn nicely?

The form element...

```
<?php

....

$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'dateTime',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\DateTime',
));
```

The template...

```
<?php

....

echo $this->formrow( $form->get('dateTime') );
```

Answer (score 3):

The calendar is only being displayed because the browser supports the HTML5 date input. ZF2 is not drawing any of it.

According to [WC3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp), datetime is an HTML5 standard but it does not appear to be widely supported.